# Correlation, skewed variable

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

My data frame/table has 3 columns and ~ 14000 rows, I would like to perform correlation between each value in rows 2 and 3, and get a matrix to plot a scatterplot with slope.

```
ID col2 col3
A1 4523 2322
A2 2323 2323
A3 2323 2323
.
.
A14000 2323 2323

       col2      col3
 col2 1.0000000  0.9817451
 col3 0.9817451  1.0000000
```

I used

```
r <- cor(mydata1, method = "pearson")
```

I would however like to get for each id their corresponding correlation score and if viable a p value any help is appreciated

I also tried using rcorr (with a transposed matrix but ended up with this error

```
Error in rcorr(mydata1, type = "pearson") : must have >4 observations
```

thank you

Comment: There's no such thing as a correlation for a single row. A single row corresponds to a single point in the scatterplot you refer to, so there's no relationship to observe.

Comment: You could calculate the residual of some sort between the regression line and your data.

Comment: Thank you, so the 0.98 value that I get does not stand good either ?